# How do I deserialize a JSON array and ignore the root node?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have next response from server -

```
{"response":[{"uid":174952xxxx,"first_name":"xxxx","last_name":"xxx"}]}
```

I am trying to deserialize this in next way -

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
```

Where T = List of VkUser, but I got error.

```
[JsonObject]
public class VkUser
{
    [JsonProperty("uid")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I always tryed

```
public class SomeDto // maybe Response as class name will fix it but I don't want such name
{
    public List<VkUser> Users {get;set;}
}
```

What deserialization options can help me?

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Oauth.Vk.Dto.VkUserApi.VkUser]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use [SelectToken](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SelectToken.htm):

```
string s =  "{\"response\":[{\"uid\":174952,\"first_name\":\"xxxx\",\"last_name\":\"xxx\"}]}";

var users = JObject.Parse(s).SelectToken("response").ToString();

var vkUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VkUser>>(users);
```

as pointed out by Brian Rogers, you can use `ToObject` directly:

```
var vkUsers = JObject.Parse(s).SelectToken("response").ToObject<List<VkUser>>();
```

Comment: Instead of converting the selected token back to a string and then re-parsing it, it would be better to use `ToObject<List<VkUser>>()` to convert the selected token directly to the final result.

Comment: your answer generate error.  if your data contains only one result then it generate error because it not array of object its single object