# How to deserialize json with table and value in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to get some info from json files like this:
mcmodfile:

```
{
  "modListVersion": 2,
  "modList": [{
    "modid": "FloatingRuins",
    "name": "FloatingRuins",
    "description": "Floating islands taken from the ground with ruins on top.",
    "version": "1.7.10.r01",
    "mcversion": "1.7.10",
    "url": "http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1009577-/",
    "updateUrl": "",
    "authorList": [ "DaftPVF", "bspkrs" ],
    "credits": "Original by DaftPVF",
    "logoFile": "",
    "screenshots": [  ],
    "parent": "",
    "requiredMods": [ "bspkrsCore@[6.12,)" ],
    "dependencies": [ "bspkrsCore@[6.12,)" ],
    "dependants": [  ],
    "useDependencyInformation": "true"
  }]
}
```

I need the "ModListVersion", "mcversion", "version", "name" and "modid".

I made a class:

```
{
    class mcmod2
    {
        [JsonProperty("modListVersion")]
        public int modListVersion;

        [JsonProperty("modList")]
        public DataRow modList;
    }
}
```

I tried to get the data with the following code:

```
String json;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(mcmodfile)) 
{
    json = r.ReadToEnd();
}

mcmod2 modinfo2;
modinfo2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<mcmod2>(json);
```

However i get the following error when I try to deserialize the file:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/8071687/

Note I have no way of changing the Json, it will have to stay as is.

I tried implementing the following: [How do I deserialize a JSON array and ignore the root node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953713/how-do-i-deserialize-a-json-array-and-ignore-the-root-node)
Didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from here: http://json2csharp.com/#

```
public class ModList {
    public string modid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string mcversion { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string updateUrl { get; set; }
    public List<string> authorList { get; set; }
    public string credits { get; set; }
    public string logoFile { get; set; }
    public List<object> screenshots { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public List<string> requiredMods { get; set; }
    public List<string> dependencies { get; set; }
    public List<object> dependants { get; set; }
    public string useDependencyInformation { get; set; } 
}

public class RootObject {
    public int modListVersion { get; set; }
    public List<ModList> modList { get; set; } 
}
```

And substitute into the code that you already have:

```
String json;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(mcmodfile)) 
{
    json = r.ReadToEnd();
}

RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: You sir, are a saint. 
I would give you an upvote, but I don't have the rep yet.

Comment: @RasmusHansen You can also use [`File.ReadAllText(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) to read the whole file in one shot without need for a `StreamReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new C# class to capture these properties (looks like a class that has string and array properties):

Maybe name it `ModItem`:

```
"modid": "FloatingRuins",
"name": "FloatingRuins",
"description": "Floating islands taken from the ground with ruins on top.",
"version": "1.7.10.r01",
"mcversion": "1.7.10",
"url": "http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1009577-/",
"updateUrl": "",
"authorList": [ "DaftPVF", "bspkrs" ],
"credits": "Original by DaftPVF",
"logoFile": "",
"screenshots": [  ],
"parent": "",
"requiredMods": [ "bspkrsCore@[6.12,)" ],
"dependencies": [ "bspkrsCore@[6.12,)" ],
"dependants": [  ],
"useDependencyInformation": "true"
```

Then change your root class to this: (make sure it's a `public` class)

```
public class mcmod2
{
    [JsonProperty("modListVersion")]
    public int modListVersion;

    [JsonProperty("modList")]
    public ModItem[] modList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using these objects:

```
public class ModList{
    [JsonProperty("modid")]
    public String ModeId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public String Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public String Version { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("mcversion")]
    public String McVersion { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public String Url { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("updateUrl")]
    public String UpdateUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("authorList")]
    public List<String> AuthorList { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("credits")]
    public String Credits { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("logoFile")]
    public String LogFile { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("screenshots")]
    public List<object> ScreenShots { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("parent")]
    public String Parent { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("requiredMods")]
    public List<String> RequiredMods { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("dependencies")]
    public List<String> Dependencies { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("dependants")]
    public List<object> Dependants { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("useDependencyInformation")]
    public String UseDependencyInformation { get; set; }
}

public class McMod{
    [JsonProperty("modListVersion")]
    public Int32 ModListVersion { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("modList")]
    public List<ModList> Mods { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization code:

```
String json;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(mcmodfile)) {
    json = r.ReadToEnd();
}
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<McMod>(json);
```