# Deserialize from a specific level in C#

Tags: c#, json

I retrieve an information from Steam about a specific game. I provide an application url: http://store.steampowered.com/app/**57690**/ and get a JSON response like:

```
{
   "57690":{   // this is dynamically got from application id above ^
      "success":true
      "data": { }
   }
}
```

I have an object, `SteamData`

```
public bool success { get; set; }

public InternalData data { get; set; }
```

and `InternalData`

```
public string name { get; set; }

public string about_the_game { get; set; }

public string supported_languages { get; set; }
...
```

I tried to deserialize above json to SteamData using:

```
SteamData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SteamData>( thatJsonAbove );
```

It's not working because there exists a root which is an **application id**...

How to deserialize only what is inside root (in this example, what's inside "57690") ?

Comment: Why do you want to deserialize from inside the root? Why not deserialize it all?

Comment: How, because the root element is dynamic, is based on application id number ...

Comment: @SnakeEyes you should do some sting manipulation before deserialize. Let say delete all data between first '{' and second '{' including '{' and then delete last two '}' and everything between them. You will preprocess your JSON string a bit before deserialize. Dirty but quick solution.

Comment: there is also a potential solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953713/how-do-i-deserialize-a-json-array-and-ignore-the-root-node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of using Newtonsoft JSON library you may try this:

```
JObject gameInfo = JObject.Parse(json);
SteamData data= gameInfo.SelectToken("57690", false).ToObject<SteamData>();
```

Since you know game's id - you can easily use this approach.